# make a variable for each item from facebook fql json output

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-fql

I want to make a variable for each item from facebook fql json output of photo albums. This is my output after I did a json encode.

```
stdClass Object ( 
 [data] => Array ( 
   [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Mobile Uploads ) 
   [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Wall Photos ) 
   [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Wall Photos ) 
   [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => New Deck and Patio - DIY ) 
   [4] => stdClass Object ( [name] => New Deck - DIY! ) 
   [5] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Honeymoon ) 
   [6] => stdClass Object ( [name] => 5/5/2012 ) 
   [7] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Cover Photos ) 
   [8] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Profile Pictures ) 
   [9] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Wedding Shower ) 
   [10] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Kuczer Christmas 2011 ) 
   [11] => stdClass Object ( [name] => A Breed Apart studio recording ) 
   [12] => stdClass Object ( [name] => New recessed lighting Kitchen ) 
   [13] => stdClass Object ( [name] => March 10, 2011 Our Engagement ) 
   [14] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Renovated Dining Room ) 
   [15] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Christmas 2010 ) 
   [16] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Florida Trip 2010 ) 
   [17] => stdClass Object ( [name] => MINE ) 
   [18] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Me ) 
   [19] => stdClass Object ( [name] => 2010 FJ Cruiser ) 
   [20] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Family ) 
   [21] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Studio Drums ) 
   [22] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Work ) 
   [23] => stdClass Object ( [name] => A Breed Apart ) 
   [24] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Dirt Biking ) 
  ) 
)
```

I want to make a variable of each photo album name such as $variable1 = "Florida Trip 2010" etc...

Comment: Why do you want that? Array/Class is a good container to not waste current scope and keep all the related data in one place

Comment: @Zerkma I guess I need to know how to extract the data and access each part of it.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you used `print_r($fb_result)` to generate this output above, you would use `$variable1 = $fb_result->data[16]->name` to set `$variable1 = "Florida Trip 2010"`;